# Call method with instance of itself in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm new to ruby, and this might be an obvious question but I really have no idea what to search for on Google to actually find what I'm looking for.

I'm doing algorithmic problems (not really relevant), and it gives me a square matrix, and asks if it has circular symmetry. I solve it like this:

```
s = STDIN.readlines.map { |x| x.chomp }.join ''
puts %w[YES NO][s == s.reverse ? 0 : 1]
```

Is it possible to put all that in one line? The only reason I can't is because I think I have to store the string and then explicitly compare it later. And it sources the string from STDIN  so I can't re-read it. Any elegant solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you feel it needs to be all on one line? Personally I'd use three lines for this in order to improve its readability.

Comment: Code golf :) Plus it might be useful sometimes. I just need to know if this functionality exists. I think its like passing an instance of itself into a block which can do what it wants (like reversing it, or something else). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Object#tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) takes a block, and passes the object to that block.  Thus, should be able to rewrite that as:

```
STDIN.readlines.map { |x| x.chomp }.join('').tap { |s| puts %w[YES NO][s == s.reverse ? 0 : 1] }
```

Although I agree with the commenter that this is only going to hurt readability.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I won't use it here but now I know the functionality exists!

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding readability, you can almost always force things on to a single line by using the `;` separator.

In your case since `s` is referenced twice you need to assign it to a variable.

Comment: I know about the semicolon, but I was wondering if you could keep chaining methods and get a reference to itself, so I can reverse that and compare it to the original?

Comment: All abord the [obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) train, then!